# Google Fusion Tables: importing csv files containing quotation marks

Tags: csv, import, google-fusion-tables, quotation-marks

I am having trouble importing rows from a tab-delimited CSV file into a fusion table database when the file contains fields with quotation marks. I still can't do it even if I change " to \"

The error message I see in the Google Drive interface is "Incomplete import at "Adding rows from file." Unable to parse your file: Quotation mark found in unquoted value at line 1, column 82".

What is the trick to solving this problem? As mentioned, \" doesn't work and neither does "" (doubling).

Comment: Try deleting the double quotes, `tr -d '"' < input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Doubling the double quotes should work. Is the value with the double quotes itself enclosed in quotes? The message indicates not; that is, foo<TAB>some "thing" here<TAB> would not work, but foo<TAB>"some ""thing"" here"<TAB> should.

Comment: No, the value with the double quotes is NOT itself quoted. My workaround is to convert all double quotes to single quotes but I really want those double quotes.